# Android studio run lint from mac terminal

Tags: macos, command-line, android-studio, lint

How can I run android lint from mac command ? I know how to run it from Android studio platform. But I have no idea to run it through gradle command line.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

I'm not sure this is what you need but you can launch `./gradlew lint` in the root directory of your project

Answer (score 0):

Go to the root directory of your project.Then type ./gradlew lint
This works for me. Cheerz.

Comment: I have been looking [here](http://www.androiddocs.com/tools/help/lint.html) and the example is 'lint --check Accessibility --HTML accessibility_report.html myproject' adding ./gradlew to the beginning does not work